# How to access 2D vector having map?

Tags: c++, stl

```
int main()
{
    map<int,string> my_map;
    vector<map<int,string> > v_temp;
    vector< vector<map<int,string> > > vectors;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
             my_map.insert(make_pair(1,"sea"));
             my_map.insert(make_pair(2,"ocean"));
            v_temp.push_back(my_map);
        }
        vectors.push_back(v_temp);
        v_temp.clear();
    }

    for(size_t i=0;i<vectors.size();i++)
        for(size_t j=0;j<vectors[i].size();j++)
            std::cout << "vectors[" << i << "][" << j << "][" << vectors[i][j].first<< " "<<vectors[i][j].second<<"]"<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
                                                                                                   ^
```

I am facing compilation issue stating no member having first and second. How can I access it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vectors[i][j]` is a `map`, which does not have a `first` or `second`. You want to loop over each `pair` of the map, and use `first` and `second` on it.

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < vectors.size(); i++ )
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < vectors[i].size(); j++ )
        for ( const auto &pair : vectors[i][j] )
            std::cout << "vectors[" << i << "][" << j << "][" << pair.first << " " << pair.second << "]" << std::endl;
```

PS: highly recommend **not** doing `using namespace std`, see [here for reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Thanks ChrisMM for explaination.